# Why is my overlay covering some elements but not all?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create my own, modal, dialog using divs:

```
html:
<div id="overlay"> </div>    
<div id="popup">  

    <input type="submit"/>
    <p>Some text</p>

</div>

css:
#overlay{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    background-color:#000;
    opacity: .75;
    z-index: -1;
}

#popup {
    position: absolute;
    text-align:center;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wfsaxton/fq7mhefa/

I'm not sure why, but my overlay is not only covering up the page, but also covering up portions of the pop-up (the background and text).  I only want it to cover up the page in the background...the pop-up should be fully above the overlay.

Any ideas what might be going on?

Comment: Because it has a higher z-index? - http://jsfiddle.net/fq7mhefa/3/

Comment: try z-index: 999 for your overlay.

Comment: popup has a higher z-index than overlay.  Therefore, I would have assumed pop-up would appear above the overlay.  Only certain tags (like input) are above the overlay.  The rest (like the text and background) are below the overlay.

Answer (score 2):

to overlay on everything, `z-index` value must be bigger then everything else. yours `-1`.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear.  I want the pop-up to be above the overlay and the overlay to be above the rest of the page.  Right now portions of the pop-up are appearing underneath the overlay even though the z-index of the popup is greater than the z-index of the overlay.

Answer (score 2):

```css
#overlay{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    background-color:#000;
    opacity: .75;
    z-index: 5;
}

.popup {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    text-align:center;
    z-index: ;
}
```

```html
<div>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</div>

    <div id="underlay">  
        <input type="submit"/>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>

<div id="overlay">  
    <div id="popup">  
        <input type="submit"/>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

You set your overlay to -1 which means it is below the default z-index:0 for nearly every html element.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear.  I want the pop-up to be above the overlay and the overlay to be above the rest of the page.  Right now portions of the pop-up are appearing underneath the overlay even though the z-index of the popup is greater than the z-index of the overlay.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh, this was so simple.  My #popup didn't have a background assigned to it so, I guess it was transparent by default.

Just added:

```
#popup {
    ....
    background-color: white;
}
```

And it works now:  http://jsfiddle.net/wfsaxton/fq7mhefa/12/